# SQL: For unique combination, show the minimum value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below query am trying to write a condition to get minimum term_cd, but this is not giving the exact result . can anybody please help  me with this.

Requirement :

- For each unique combination of `TNT.STU_ID` and `TNT.MINOR_CD`, display the `TNT.TERM_CD` with the minimum `TNT.TERM_SEQ_NUM`

Code:

```
SELECT
    pt.[TERM_CD]
FROM
    [SR0TNT] pt
WHERE 
    TERM_SEQ_NUM = (SELECT MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) 
                    FROM [SR0TNT] AS t2 
                    WHERE pt.STU_ID = t2.STU_ID
                    --and pt.TERM_CD = t2.TERM_CD
                      AND pt.STU_ID = '003899725 '
```

Comment: There's a closing `)` missing at the end of your subquery, and is your `STU_ID` really a string of numbers with a *trailing space* ?

Answer (score 1):

Few ways to do it really..  This is one of the easiest.

```
SELECT
    STU_ID,
    MINOR_CD,
    [TERM_CD],
    TERM_SEQ_NUM
FROM
    (SELECT
        STU_ID,
        MINOR_CD,
        [TERM_CD],
        TERM_SEQ_NUM,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STU_ID,MINOR_CD ORDER BY TERM_SEQ_NUM) Rn
     FROM
        [SR0TNT]
     WHERE
        STU_ID = '003899725 '
    ) pt
WHERE
    Rn = 1
```

If if were to use your method it would look like this.

```
SELECT
    pt.[TERM_CD]
FROM
    [SR0TNT] pt
WHERE
    pt.STU_ID = '003899725 '
    AND pt.TERM_SEQ_NUM = (
        SELECT MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) 
        FROM [SR0TNT] AS t2 
        WHERE pt.STU_ID = t2.STU_ID AND pt.MINOR_CD = t2.MINOR_CD
    )
```

You can also self join..

```
SELECT
    pt.[TERM_CD]
FROM
    [SR0TNT] pt
    JOIN (SELECT 
                STU_ID, 
                MINOR_CD, 
                MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) AS TERM_SEQ_NUM 
          FROM 
                [SR0TNT] 
         GROUP BY 
                STU_ID, MINOR_CD) t2 ON t2.STU_ID = pt.STU_ID 
                       AND t2.MINOR_CD = pt.MINOR_CD 
                       AND t2.TERM_SEQ_NUM = pt.TERM_SEQ_NUM 
WHERE 
    pt.STU_ID = '003899725 '
```

Comment: I like the ROW_NUMBER() method the best. Just add OP's pt.STU_ID filter to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select pt.[TERM_CD]  --You don't need MINOR_CD as a SELECT field?
FROM [SR0TNT] pt
INNER JOIN (  --This inner join will act like a filter to exclude rows that do not have the minimum TERM_SEQ_NUM
   select TNT.TERM_CD,TNT.STU_ID,TNT.MINOR_CD, MIN(TNT.TERM_SEQ_NUM) as minm
        FROM [SR0TNT] TNT
        GROUP BY TNT.TERM_CD,TNT.STU_ID,TNT.MINOR_CD
) SUB
    ON pt.TERM_CD = SUB.TERM_CD
    AND pt.MINOR_CD = SUB.MINOR_CD
    AND pt.STU_ID = SUB.STU_ID
    AND pt.TERM_SEQ_NUM = SUB.minm
WHERE pt.STU_ID = '003899725 '
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,                                                                  I tried using this above query getting error as below                                        Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I think in @JamieD77's answer, the first query there is the best.  Did it work for you?

Comment: by using the above query am getting mutiple rows. where as i need only the term which has minimum seq no for each unique combination.

Comment: I've changed my answer.  You could try that.  Let us know if you're still getting multiple rows.

Comment: OK, I added another GROUP BY at the bottom, to try to eliminate multiple rows.

Comment: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97443/discussion-between-baodad-and-sam).